# EKEventview controller not showing navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I used the following code to view the event. But navigation bar doesn't visible.

```
EKEventViewController *addController = [[EKEventViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
addController.event = self.event;
addController.allowsEditing = YES;
addController.allowsCalendarPreview = YES;
[self.navigationController presentViewController:addController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with Present viewcontroller you need to Add sepreated NavigationController for UIViewcontroller like:-

```
EKEventViewController *addController = [[EKEventViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EKEventViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:addController];
addController.event = self.event;
addController.allowsEditing = YES;
addController.allowsCalendarPreview = YES;


if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)])
    {
           [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {

        [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
    }
```